# Why am I getting this error in futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDxJ2.png)

I have no idea why I'm getting an error

Comment: Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will return null if the condition is not fulfilled.
You need to return something outside of your conditional statement or in a else condition

```
FutureBuilder<List<Mesajlar>>(   
  future: mesajlarifetir),
  builder: (context ‚snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
    var mesailistesi = snapshot. data;
    return ListView.builder (
  );} 
  return CircularProgressIndicator(); //Add this line
})
```

Comment: note: [the official guidance](/help/how-to-answer) is that you should avoid answering questions that "_are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem._". In this case, the question is making [inappropriate usage of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) where it should instead be providing a [mre] in the form of formatted text.